# Parsing the string for a calculator in C Programming

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing

I am building a scientific calculator.

The functioning of this calc will go in this way...

1. User will put scientific expressions like `cos(45)`.
2. The calculator will contain 3 supported functions like `sin, cos, tan` for now.
3. a while loop will detect `sin` and will store it in `container[5]`.
4. A function `int match(char* exp)` will take string `cos` from `container[5]` and will search  if it gets matched with any element in `supportedFn[3]`.
5. If match is found, the string `sin` from `container[5]` will get transferred to the position 0 of `char* tokens[30]`.  (function setting Tokens[30] is  not implemented).
6. The `container[5]` will **emptied** by using function `void makeBlank(char* box)` so that `container[5]` can be used for storing detected strings like `multiple digit numbers`, `(`, `)`, etc.

Later on the completed token array will look like `tokens[30] = {"cos", "(", "45", ")"}`.

**So I am facing problem in `match()` function I am using for loop inside it**

But its not giving correct return values pls help. How do I implement `match()` properly so that it returns 1 if it finds `cos` at any position in `supportedFn[3]`?

Below is my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* supportedFn[3]= {"sin", "cos", "tan"};

char* expression = "cos(45)";    // Entered by the user

char container[5];        // array to store functions entered by user (Ex. cos)




// Function to make container blank after detecting

void makeBlank(char* box){       
    int i = strlen(box);
    while(box[0] != '\0'){
        box[i] = '\0';
        i--;
    }
}

int match(char* exp){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(strcmp(exp, supportedFn[i]) == 0){
            break;
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}




int main(){
    
    // For storing string function like sin, cos, tan

    int i = 0;
    while(expression[i] != '\0'){
        if(isalpha(expression[i])){
            container[i] = expression[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{i++;}
    }

    printf("%d is the value\n", match(container)); //Not getting proper result
```

`Not able to implement further if match() is not working properly`

Comment: Have you tried running your code in a debugger and seeing what is being passed to `match`?

Comment: Just curious: Consider what happens in that while loop in `main` when the if-test is *false* on any iteration. Which slot in `container` are you indexing ? More to the point, what, if anything, was placed in the i'th slot on the *prior* iteration? Nothing. It will remain what it was before, which as a global, will be a null char. If that is the intended behavior, so be it, but it's an odd way of accomplishing it.

Comment: In the function `match`, you don't need to break the loop because you return one. When you break the loop, it stops the loop immediately and exits the function eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
    if(strcmp(exp, supportedFn[i]) == 0){
        break;
        return 1;
    }
```

is incorrect as you are terminating the loop before you get a chance to return 1.  Just remove the `break;` statement to return 1 when your keyword is found. Also you should return 0 only when all loops have been executed without finding the keyword:

```
int match(char* exp){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(strcmp(exp, supportedFn[i]) == 0){
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code has worked for me. Thanks mmixLinus